# How can I round only the left corners of a button?

Tags: html, css

This is the referential image of the button:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be able to use the short-hand for `border-radius` like so:

```css
button {
  border-radius: 2rem 0 0 2rem;
}
```

```html
<button>Hello World</button>
```